# Yii CDbCommand methods not applying

Tags: php, sql, yii

I have the following code that creates a CDbCommand in Yii:

```
$cmd = Yii::app()->db->createCommand(array(
    'select'=>'CMUM, CPRO, CUN, DMUN50',
    'from'=>'PROVINCIAS',
    'where'=>'CPRO = :CPRO'
));
$cmd->bindParam(":CPRO", $CPRO, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$cmd->setLimit(2);
```

This should limit the query result to 2 rows, but I get all available rows. Why?

Regards

Comment: change   $command->bindParam to $cmd->bindParam and try

Comment: @ramamoorthy_villi Oops, that was a copy/paste typo, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set limit before binding params. Because when you bind the params it internally prepare the PDO statement. So you cannot set the limit after that.

```
$cmd = Yii::app()->db->createCommand(array(
    'select'=>'CMUM, CPRO, CUN, DMUN50',
    'from'=>'PROVINCIAS',
    'where'=>'CPRO = :CPRO'
));
$cmd->setLimit(2);
$cmd->bindParam(":CPRO", $CPRO, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Comment: One more thing. How can I get the query that will be sent to the server with the variables replaced? (getText returns the placeholders instead of the actual values)

Comment: PDO queries logging is not easy. You should enable Yii logs and view the queries executing. http://www.larryullman.com/2013/09/23/debugging-database-operations-in-yii/. Optionally you can view the mysql log